# How to style a p element so that it always takes 2 rows to accommodate long text

Tags: html

The page display images with caption at the bottom. The space for the caption is relatively small, so for some pictures, the caption is displayed in 2 lines. It's really visually unpleasant.

How to get something like this

```
This text is too long, so it's                    This text is fine.
will be broken into 2 lines                       **** empty line any way ***
```

The caption is supposed to be display in a p tag.

```
<p>img.productDescrion</p>
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Hi, css3  word-wrap can be helpful in your case? What happens if the text will be broken into 3 or more lines?

Comment: @Sfili_81, I don't think there will be such case. Case provide some code illustrate your suggestion?

Comment: Would you like the p tags to have the same height?regardless of how much text there is?